# How to iterate or read all the rows on selected columns

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have this excel table where it reads the specific column, and now after reading  it should check on it and if it has a value it should put another value on its next row. For example 
on Column D (row 1, cell 3) it has value on it so it should write on Column F that "has age" on (row 1, cell 5)or whatever it should be written. and so on and so for until the rest of the column D is finished and it should be too in Column F

```
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);

        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

         Row row = sheet.getRow(0);// pababa SPECIFY SAAN ILALAGAY
        // Specific cell number 
        Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

          row = sheet.getRow(i);
            if (row != null) {

                cell.setCellValue("qwe");

            }
        }
```

### //another code -------------------------------------

```
             for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
             row = sheet.createRow(i);
             cell = row.createCell(2);
             cell.setCellValue(100);
             }
             } else {
             System.out.println("nasa else to");
             }

             /*  XSSFCell exceltaym = (XSSFCell) row.getCell(0);   //nag convert nang time to integer na na compute till line 177[enter image description here][1]
             if (exceltaym == null) {
             cell.setCellValue(9); 


             }else
             {
             System.out.println("this statement is on else code ");
             }
```

Comment: stack didnt allow me to upload  a pic, so if you ever having trouble trying to understand Im willing to send a pic on email or whereever

Comment: You can upload images to http://imgur.com and link to them -- someone with enough reputation will likely embed them for you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand, but can't you just use this formula in column F to check that column D is not empty?

`=IF(D1<>"", "has age")`